# Short statement for if-not-none-then-none-else-default

Tags: python, python-3.x

Env: Python 3.8

Is there a shorthand statement for something like this:

```
def if_not_none_then_none_else_default(some_value, default):
    if some_value:
        return None
    else:
        return default
```

Comment: `None if some_value else default`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [ternary](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html):

```
def if_not_none_then_none_else_default(some_value, default):
    return None if some_value else default
```